# Error when observer is executed after order is placed

Tags: module, event-observer, magento2.3, onepage-checkout, object-manager

I created a module in order to save order data to a custom table:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="order_place_navision" instance="MyVendor\SalesOrderSync\Observer\SaveOrder"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer/SaveOrder.php:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\SalesOrderSync\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

class SaveOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $logger;
    private $state;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
    ) {
        $this->_layout = $context->getLayout();
        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_state = $state;

        try {
            $this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            // nothing to do
        }

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
        $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
        $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
        $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
        $objDate = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime');
        $date = $objDate->gmtDate();

        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO custom_sap_orders (entity_id, order_id, sent, timestamp) Values (''," .
            $orderId .
            ", '" .
            "0" .
            "', '" .
            $date .
            "')" ;
        $connection->query($sql);

    }
}
```

But I get this error when I complete an order:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Captcha\Model\Checkout\ConfigProvider

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Captcha\Model\Checkout\ConfigProvider
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Captcha\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\Captcha\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Captcha\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Captcha\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php:250]
#5 Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->getPlugin('Magento\Checkout...', 'login_captcha') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:144]
#6 Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#7 Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getConfig', array(), array(array('customer_cart', 'login_captcha'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar/Interceptor.php:26]
#8 Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->getConfig() called at [app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml:45]
#9 include('/var/www/html/ap...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor#0000000012d1f258000000005dbf9a65#, '/var/www/html/ap...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/ap...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1094]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1098]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:671]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('minicart') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:533]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('minicart') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('minicart', true) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:518]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('minicart')
#20 call_user_func_array(array(&Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template#0000000012d1f267000000005dbf9a65#, 'getChildHtml'), array('minicart')) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:82]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->__call('getChildHtml', array('minicart')) called at [app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/templates/html/header.phtml:269]
#22 include('/var/www/html/ap...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template#0000000012d1f267000000005dbf9a65#, '/var/www/html/ap...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/ap...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1094]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1098]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:671]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('porto_header') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:533]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('porto_header') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('porto_header', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:954]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', array(), array(array('layout-model-cac...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:39]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000012d1f40e000000005dbf9a65#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000012d1f40e000000005dbf9a65#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000012d1f40e000000005dbf9a65#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000012d1f40e000000005dbf9a65#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000012d1f40e000000005dbf9a65#), array(array('result-messages', 'result-builtin-c...', 'result-varnish-c...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:39]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000012d1f40e000000005dbf9a65#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:141]
#49 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#50 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#0000000012d1f408000000005dbf9a65#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Any idea in order to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove generation folder or in version 2.2 remove the generated folder.

`rm -rf generated/`

flush the cache. It should work then. its because the interceptor file needs to be re-created or refresh.

I hope its working to you.